# Is grammar really so important?

Tags: discussion

I recently noticed that questions (and answers) that are worded poorly due to the poster's bad English skills are unequally upvoted (or ever downvoted) compared to the posts of native English speakers.

Is it fair? I've always believed that the most important part of a post on Stack Overflow is the code solving the problem (or describing the problem).

Comment: Do you have examples? I would rather expect edits to get that solved. Language is still an important part of a high-quality question and answer.

Comment: Spelling is very important.  No point in adding content that can never be googled back.  That's a very simple problem to solve, getting an English spell checker in your browser is a no-brainer.  Grammar, meh, you merely risk not getting an answer because nobody can understand what you are asking.  Everybody understands code.  Well, if it is close enough to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Grammar is important because poor grammar obfuscates good content.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The best solution when you see poor grammar in a question or an answer, and you feel strongly that you understand the poster's intent, is to edit the question or answer to try to fix the grammatical issues without subverting the poster's intent. This will help all involved, including and especially future visitors to this site with similar questions.

Comment: See also the [why vote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) in the help center. Is states to dowvote when a post *fails to communicate information*

Comment: Often my edits concerning only grammar and/or spelling get refused based on the ground of being to "minimal"

Answer (score 6):

To add to what the others have said, there is a *big* difference between some grammar or spelling problems where the OP doesn't know the language (and cannot be reasonably expected to study a dictionary long enough to get it right), and where the OP just couldn't be bothered to capitalise "I" or include the apostrophe in "it's".

I downvote *lazy* questions on the spot and make no apology for that.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you punish minor typing mistakes and let severe shortcomings stand uncorrected, because the OP "cannot reasonably [be] expected to study a dictionary"?

Comment: @Alexander You almost got it, but then you fell into the mistake of conflating "mistakes" with "a lack of due diligence".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I agree with you. A poster here can be a native of any language other than English.
But the poster should post his/her question in such a way that it can be understand by any viewer.

So grammar is important in this way, but grammar mistakes in a question should not cause others to downvote the question because of poor English skills.