# Automatically flag excessive txting vocabulary use for low-quality queue

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, low-quality-posts, quality-filter

As mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253780/is-it-ok-to-downvote-questions-because-of-bad-grammar), it isn't particularly difficult to distinguish posters who are native English speakers, but don't care enough to write a good question, from non-native speakers who are trying.

Usually, this is most obvious from texting abbreviations ("u", "r", "i", "lol", "wtf", "plz", etc.) and bad capitalization / punctuation. I know it's a heuristic, but as a heuristic it does tend to be pretty reliable.

Many of [these posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22+U+r+%22+is%3Aquestion), for example, could at least benefit from some cleaning up. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873632/how-to-handle-music-code), off that list, is barely intelligible, and would be way clearer with only 20 seconds of editing. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827422/how-to-drag-and-drop-from-local-filesystem-to-treepanel), also randomly from that list, suffers from the same issue.

The heuristic I used for that search was pretty basic, but something which looked for, say, five occurences of anything from that list would winnow down the list even further. [This alone](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22+U+r+%22+%22+i+%22+%22+plz+%22+is%3Aquestion) brought the list way down, and every one of those posts could use editing.

Generally, what I've noticed from doing that kind of search are clarity issues. A significant percentage of those posts take way longer to read than they need to.

---

*Edit:* As mentioned by @bluefeet in the comments below, we already have a pretty good list of [words which tend to be indicative of awfulness](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185390/spelling-clean-up-jquerry-and-querry/185424#185424).

Comment: Why does a flag have to generated for the moderators?  Why do moderators need to intervene when the community can edit this out?  Side note: I personally despise this type of txtspeak in posts.

Comment: actually 3 out of the top 5 are false hits ""s u p e r n a t u r a l", "h e u r e msgstr", "but not like this H O U R" etc

Comment: Moderators are not proofreaders, and the low quality queue already serves this purpose.

Comment: @Plutonix True, which is why that particular one should definitely not be the entire substring matching algorithm. The second search attempt was pretty good, though.

Comment: @MadScientist Ah, okay... That's actually what I meant, anyway. Just... Someone look at it, because it probably needs looking at.

Comment: You want to see bad - search [thx](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thx%22) or [plz](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22+plz+%22) alone.

Comment: @bluefeet *wince* I... I don't want to see bad. (But I clicked the `plz` link. Impressive.)

Comment: @ParthianShot or see [this list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185424/164200). This has been discussed before on MSE.

Comment: @bluefeet `this list` That's a nice list. Just generally; a lot of good applications for such a list. `been discussed before` You have my apologies- I was not aware of that.

Comment: Just FYI, text speak is already something that our quality filter factors in. Excessive use of text speak, along with other markers of a poor quality question, will prevent a person from ever submitting it. [I persuaded Shog a while back to turn it up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174097/is-it-time-to-tighten-up-the-question-quality-filter). Of course, it would seem perfectly logical to dump questions with an intermediate score into the "very low quality" queue.

Answer (score -4):

The Low Quality Posts queue is for posts that are so completely awful that they need to be burned with fire (i.e. deleted).  It's not for posts that just need some editing love to be more readable.

The appropriate action for posts with txtspk in the LQP queue is to mark them as okay (assuming they don't happen to meet one of the other requirements for deletion).

Currently there is no queue for, "this post could use some editing love".  And given how easy it is for people who want to edit posts to find posts that need editing, I'm not sure it's worth creating such a queue.

Comment: Well, there is a reason that editing posts kick them immediately out of the Low Quality Posts queue. That review queue is also supposed to help find things that just need a little love, so I don't see a problem with the low quality heuristics taking txtspeak into account as a quality measure.

Comment: @BradLarson Well, [currently about 2.5% of actions in the LQP queue are editing actions](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/199503/how-often-do-people-edit-in-lqp-review).  (3.3% if you don't count skips as actions)  So it's not really being leveraged all that much for editing.

Comment: True, not a lot is worth editing in there, but the stuff that is can be pulled out. If txtspeak isn't already part of the heuristics for kicking new posts into Low Quality review, I see no harm in adding it.

Comment: *"The Low Quality Posts queue is for posts that are so completely awful that they need to be burned with fire (i.e. deleted)."* I thought that's what automatic rejection was for? Why do we accept crap that just needs to be burned with fire?

Comment: @CodyGray Because automated tools can't have a 100% success rate at determine if a given post should be deleted, the false positive rate is high enough that, to ensure good content isn't deleted, the automated algorithm just adds a flag if it's not really really sure that the post is bad so that a human can check its work.