# No stupid questions? Won't downvotes discourage genuine people with issues who are not good with words?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

No stupid questions... right?

I see many questions being downvoted without any comments etc. (I have faced this myself) which are genuine issues and I believe are fit for Stack Overflow. Maybe the wording is stupid (not all are good with that), and maybe the person is very ignorant, but if he is facing an issue isn't SO meant to help him solve it? Is this site for answers or for making people better writers?

Don't you think you are discouraging new users who might look for some other forum to avoid such situations?

I am sure this question will be downvoted a lot. ;)

Comment: latest example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648265/how-to-get-value-from-another-ruby-script

Comment: _"I am sure this question will be downvoted a lot. ;)"_ That can be arranged.
I'll just be blunt here: From what I can see, you tend to have poor formatting in your questions. That makes questions harder to understand, resulting in downvotes. While the problem may be real enough, if users can't figure out what the actual problem is, they can't help you.

Comment: As @Cerbrus pointed out, your formatting is poor, specially in the e.g. Try to improve the formatting and consider that there are so many poor questions out there that if everyone had to post a comment for every down-vote we would have a productivity loss of 1000% in our economic system. EDIT: take a look at the improved formatting of your question. It is just so much better now to read.

Comment: Also, if someone uses the word _"ignorant"_ on SO, my mouse automagically hovers over the downvote button.

Comment: Once again, there are of course stupid questions _depending on the context_. Asking SO where your car is parked would be a very stupid question. And no, SO is not meant to _help_ individual askers, it is meant to be a repository of valuable programming knowledge; where valuable means the question can be helpful to a broader audience of people and not just OP.

Comment: Related: [Is it OK to downvote questions because of bad grammar?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253780/is-it-ok-to-downvote-questions-because-of-bad-grammar)

Comment: Thanks @Cerbrus and Theolodis. I am open to constructive criticism. And if the questions formatting is wrong why not edit it. It will be a good learning for the OP.

Comment: Editing a question takes way more time than a downvote. I don't always have the time to spare, to make an edit. I imagine that's the same for other users.

Comment: @Some_other_guy I will not start to edit really poor formatted questions. Sometimes I do, but for sure I will not do that as full-time job. So I'll stick with down-voting poor questions and move on to good ones ;)

Comment: @Cerbrus: Well maybe, makes sense...but how will people learn if they see just downvotes. I guess it will just discourage them from asking questions here. And that's my exact question here. If new users just come to read old questions and answers and don't ask questions here how will this grow. I know many people who ask questions in different forum and use SO in read-only mode.

Comment: Yes, writing skills surely influence the understandability and therefore the quality of questions and answers. It would be a bad idea not to take the presentation into account. The result is that a poorly written question may still get some answers but very likely not as many. That is reasonable.

Comment: @Some_other_guy I heard SO gets a lot of new questions every day, more or less more than ever before. So growing seems not be a problem. On the other hand for all the users of SO that look for answers it is important that the questions are written clearly otherwise how can they understand them and learn from them. A minimal quality of the questions and answers is necessary for the success.

Comment: Whoever said "there are no stupid questions" was an idiot.  Don't listen to idiots.

Comment: @Will: Lol...but it's true... But personally I encourage people asking question however stupid (because some people don't ask thinking it is stupid when it's not) and that's the way people learn.

Answer (score 10):

### Clarity is Key

I might be wrong, but I believe most users on SO, have short bursts of activity where they search for questions they can answer. If they are giving up their time to try to answer a question, they want to ideally be able to read through the question in one go and understand the problem.

If they struggle to understand the question, but they have tried, then it is likely that others will too and they are within their rights to cast negative votes based on that experience and move on.

If you aren't completely comfortable with wording questions, find a colleague or someone that can read what you're about to post and see if it's clear to them.

Comment: If you aren't completely comfortable with wording questions, find a colleague on someone that can read what you're about to post and see if it's clear to them. - This sounds to be a good idea. Will follow it.